# How to make fullpage scroll more intuitive

Tags: jquery

I am applying a fullpage scroll but there is a significant delay after scrolling before it slides to the next section and I want to achieve a smoother quicker transition, can anyone help me achieve this?

https://codepen.io/glittergirl/pen/jpmvqB

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //options here
        autoScrolling:true,
    });

    //methods
    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
});
```

Comment: While not an answer to your question, I'd suggest using https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your version was over complicating things, try this.

```
$(function(){
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionSelector: 'section',
    scrollOverflow: true
  });
});
```

See working example. https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/4xj067Lk/

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the speed here::

```
'transition':'all 0.3s',
'-webkit-transition':'all 0.3s'
```